# Numpy dot in a for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code where I use numpy.dot to speed up my calculations.

```
u = numpy.zeros((l, l))
wp = numpy.zeros((l,2))
# some code which edits u and wp
for x in range(N):
    wavg = numpy.dot(wp[:, 0], wp[:, 1])
    wp[:, 0] = 1.0/wavg*numpy.dot(u, numpy.multiply(wp[:, 0], wp[:, 1]))
```

For small l the slowest part is the outer loop. Now I ask myself if there is a way to get rid of this loop?

Edit: In mathematical Terms this code would look like this
[image: In mathematical Terms this code would look like this]

Comment: In that `some code` line are you growing `u` and `wp`?  What's the final shape of those two arrays?  What is `wp[:,0]` and `wp[:,1]` in the equation?

Comment: That is correct. They are not changing their shape but the entries will be of course defined in the code which is a bit longer and in my opinion shouldn't matter here. wp[:,0] is f and wp[:,1] corresponds to w. The number of time steps is N

Comment: You could precompute V_ij = U_ij*w_j for a small performance increase here

Comment: Do you care about `f(1), f(2), ....`, or only f(N)? It seems to me like you could calculate `wavg` just once in after the loop

Comment: I actually just care about f(N). I will try both things you suggested but I assume that this doesn't make it much faster.

Comment: @HighwayJohn: See my answer - calculating wavg once allows you to eliminate the loop

Comment: Are `~f_i(t+1)` and `f_j(t)` the same thing?  That is, do you take the result at `t` and plug it back in?  If so, that step is rarely vectorizable.

Comment: Yep, thats the case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small improvement by pre-calculating a term

```
u = np.zeros((l, l))
wp = np.zeros((l,2))
# some code which edits u and wp

m = u*wp[:, 1]
for x in range(N):
    wavg = np.dot(wp[:, 0], wp[:, 1])
    wp[:, 0] = 1.0/wavg*np.dot(m, wp[:, 0])
```

But we can do better - instead of calculating the average every time, we can do it in just the last iteration:

```
m = u*wp[:, 1]
for x in range(N - 1):
    wp[:, 0] = np.dot(m, wp[:, 0])

wavg = np.dot(wp[:, 0], wp[:, 1])
wp[:, 0] = 1.0/wavg*np.dot(m, wp[:, 0])
```

But there's one more thing we can do - that loop can be replaced with matrix exponentiation:

```
m = u*wp[:, 1]
wp[:, 0] = np.linalg.matrix_power(m, N-1).dot(wp[:, 0])
wavg = np.dot(wp[:, 0], wp[:, 1])
wp[:, 0] = 1.0/wavg*np.dot(m, wp[:, 0])
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be way slower. However, if you can precompute `np.linalg.matrix_power(m, N-1)`, then it will be way faster

Comment: That looks really nice and it works in principle. It also speeds up the code. But there is a big problem. When N becomes large wavg becomes very small. For N = 6000, wavg is already `wavg =  4.58187259646e-58`. For even larger N wavg will be saved as 0 and I get an error.

Comment: You could break N into smaller chunks, normalizing every 50 steps or so, in which case you can precompute `np.linalg.matrix_power(m, 50)` and use that repeatedly

Comment: Okay, I guess that is a good idea. I was also thinking about this

Answer (score 4):

I'm still confused about the shape of your arrays, and the relation between the code and equation.

But just looking at the equation, I think it can be calculated as:

```
In [515]: n,m = 3,4

In [516]: U = np.ones((n,m))

In [517]: w = np.ones((m,))

In [518]: f = np.ones((m,))

In [519]: np.einsum('ij,j,j->i',U,w,f)
Out[519]: array([ 4.,  4.,  4.])
```

For the moment I'm concerned with getting dimensions to match; not on final values.  The calculation is simple enough that it doesn't need the Einstein notation, but `einsum` makes the translation almost mechanical.

The `dot` equivalent is

```
In [520]: np.dot(U, w*f)
Out[520]: array([ 4.,  4.,  4.])
```

Since this evolves over time, the `f` of iteration depending on the value of the previous (and this external value `w(t)`), it's hard to remove that loop; we can just make the contents faster.

Comment: Why should this be faster?